# How to show a popular post in wordpress in last 24 hours?

Tags: popular-posts

I have the query_post on my codes. This will display the popular post of all time.
But I want to dispaly the popular post in past 24 hours. How do I do that?

```
<?php query_posts('orderby=comment_count&order=DESC&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));?>
```

I have seen many answer here related to this topic, But not exactly this code.
Following is my full code.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: try
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
                 <div class="filter_bar"><div class="fb_title">Blog Archieves</div></div>
          <div id="content_inner">
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Alert' ) ) : ?>
            <!--Wigitized 'Alert' for the home page -->
        <?php endif ?>

         <div id="blog_wrapper">


 <?php query_posts('showposts=15&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

          <ul class="lp_lists">
            <li class="lp_container">
                <div class="lp_left">
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) :?>
                    <div class="thumbnailimg">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="lp_desc">
                     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div><!--lp left ends-->
                <div class="lp_right">
                    <div class="lp_title">
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lp_category">
                        <?php the_category(', ') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lp_dates">
                       <?php echo get_the_date(); ?><span class="spacer">at</span><?php echo get_the_time(); ?>
                    </div>
                 <?php if(function_exists(kkLikeButton())){kkLikeButton();}?>

                </div><!--lp right ends-->
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </li><!--lp container ends-->
            </ul>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
           <div class="no-results">
            <p><strong><?php _e('There has been an error.'); ?></strong></p>
            <p><?php _e('We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.'); ?></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); /* outputs the default Wordpress search form */ ?>
        </div><!--noResults-->
        <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

        <div class="oldernewer">
            <p class="older"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></p>
            <p class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></p>
        </div><!--.oldernewer-->
             </div><!--content_inner ends-->
    </div><!--#content-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: you mean the current day posts?

Comment: yeah. the current day popular post. the popular post should be the popular post of the day form all the posts I have got, not only from the posts form today but from all the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/ use this plugin

you can use
Time Range - list those posts of your blog that have been the most popular ones within a specific time range (eg. last 24 hours, last 7 days, last 30 days, etc.)!

go to plugins page just try i think you will satisfy

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use `query_posts`. For clarification you can read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

To show current day posts only, you can use below argument for your query:

Just replace these two lines in your file:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=15&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

With this:

```
<?php
 $_args = array(
     'showposts' => 15,
     'orderby' => 'comment_count',
     'order' => 'DESC',
     'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
     'date_query' => array(
         array(
            'day' => date('d'),
        'monthnum' => date('M'),
        'year' => date('Y'),
         ),
      ),
     'meta_key' => 'kklike_value',
     'meta_value' => 'meta_value_num',
 );

    $loop = new WP_Query($_args);
    if ($loop->have_posts()) :
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

**Edited:**

Ok you have to add these two more keys and values. See above for full code.

```
'meta_key' => 'kklike_value',
'meta_value' => 'meta_value_num',
```

Comment: the thing is I am new to wordpress. So you have to explain me where to put this code. Shall I just delete the query_posts line and replace with your code or what?

Comment: @diwasbhattarai see my edited answer!

Comment: you can see my page code. I have edited my question.

Comment: I tested your code. It just show the most recent post. It doesnot work. I want to show the popular post from last 24 hours not recent post.

Comment: Popular posts in which context? Popular post by comment count? or what?

Comment: I had installed the plugin KK I Like It. You can search in internet. It would be nice if you tell me to show the post according to the like I get through that plugin. But if it is complicated than according to view and comment count is also accepted.

Comment: @diwasbhattarai See edited!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Rahil is correct and the only reason it might not work with you is he has used **[date_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)** in his answer which works for WordPress version `3.7` and above, so if you are using a lower version it wont work for you. 
You can try the below code to get this done

Assumption is by 24 hours means for the very day

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'showposts' => 15,
    'orderby'   => 'comment_count',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'paged'     => get_query_var('paged'),
    'monthnum'  => date('m'),
    'day'       => date('d'),
    'year'      => date('Y')
);

   $loop = new WP_Query($args);
   if ($loop->have_posts()) :
       while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```